# Why would anybody ever override methods if program were designed correctly?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, overriding

I understand how overriding works and what it does. What I don't understand is why anybody would need to use it, if classes were designed "correctly"?

For example, let's say that I have a class called Animal and I've added a speak method. And then afterwards, I have a few classes that inherit from Animal such as cows, dogs and cats. But each of these "speak" differently. Cows do: system.out.println( "moo"). dogs do "woof" and cats do "meow".

My question is if cows, dogs and cats all have to override the speak method, then why would I even put speak in the Animal class in the first place?

I've tried researching for the reason online and on Stackoverflow, but nobody seems to be giving me a concrete answer. The best I have is that I should have really used an interface instead (from the posts that claim that extending from concrete classes is EVIL).

Comment: Let's say I have an List of Animals containing Cow, Dog, and Cat. I want to make all the Animals speak. `for(Animal a: animals) a.speak();`

Comment: Your example is a bad one, but let's continue with it. Perhaps you create an `Animal` and not a subclass of it and this `Animal` needs to be able to talk. Also, maybe not all subclasses override the method. `Cat` and `Cow` overrides it but `Dog` is happy with the implementation of its parent class.

Comment: If you wouldn't put the speak method in the Animal class, then the Animal wouldn't be able to speak. But it's the contract of an animal, that it can speak, so the method has to be in the class.

Comment: You guys are the best! Thanks so much. Understand 100% now:)

Comment: One very important word: Polymorphism. You can have a list of `Animal`s, which all can use this speak behavior to behave, as a cat does not speak like a dog so they have to implement the behavior independently. You don't have to cast all these `Animal`s to their respective classes in order to get the output you care about, what they say when they speak.

Comment: Your example is one that would be best realized by an abstract class: you can either provide a default implementation or not, and you can't instantiate an Animal because all Animals should be instances of a subclass, e.g. the class of a species.

Comment: Removed a lot of meta comments. If there are questions about whether this question is on-topic, please ask a question on [meta]. Please do not use the comments for that kind of discussion.

Answer (score 5):

One answer is polymorphism.

when speak is defined at the `Animal` level it allows me to do this.

```
ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
animals.add(new Dog("Charlie"));
animals.add(new Bird("Tweety"));
animals.add(new Duck("Cheese and Quackers"));

for( Animal a : animals ) 
    a.speak();
```

Since speak has a base behavior defined in the base class, I can be guaranteed there will be SOME speak behavior so I can call that behavior safety from the base class without risk of calling a method that doesn't exist on a class. If the particular class has a more complicated implementation, that's good, but I'm at the least guaranteed to have SOME implementation. I don't want to have to worry if `Giraffe` hasn't implemented speak -- by extending animal which already has a minimum routine defined, by contract I am guaranteed that there is some implementation I can use.

You can accomplish this also with interfaces, but there are cases where Interfaces are less convenient than extension, since interface requires all implementing classes have their own implementation, which in many cases is a time waster.

This brings me to my second answer : simplicity.

You say (paraphrased) 'if all object have to implement speak and all speak differently'. That's a big assumption. What if 90% of animals speak the same and only some animals speak different. Consider `Monkey`, `Human`, `Cat`, and `Telepathic Cat`.  Here I might argue that the first three would speak the same way. The only person that needs its own speak is `Telepathic Cat` since it uses a different method to speak. In this case its useful to define speak only twice. Once in `Animal` and a second time in the special case with `Telepathic Cat`. This make code maintenance far simpler. If everyone's speak is truly different, then maybe an interface is what you want, but if most animals speak the same, then inheritance wins the day.

Comment: I'm really interested who downvotes all those answers, an explanation would be welcome.

Comment: Well, i asked the original question and I thought it was a wonderful and helpful explanation. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

If Animal didn't have a speak() method, then if you did this

```
Animal a = new Dog();
```

you couldn't do

```
a.speak();
```

even if Dog had a `speak()` method

Answer (score 1):

Just so that when you have an Animal instance you would be sure that it can speak(). thats the principle of design by contract. It is assured to you by the Animal class (contract) that any sibling will be able to speak. The fact that any sibling has its own way of doing that, well thats Polymorphism.

For your side question which is as i understand why would one use abstract methods over interfaces - its helpful when you have some sort of a standart way or a default way to implement the method in the parent class even if you dont have the ability to fully implement it there, also an abstract method differ from a regular method by that it will force subclasses to implemnt that method as it is with interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, abstract classes like the Animal class, in your case, are designed to provide a specific interface for all of the subclasses of Animal. The abstract part of Animal allows the programmer to realize he *must* create a method for `speak`. After all, every Animal speaks differently, and there's no "default" way for an Animal to speak.

Answer (score 0):

That's the essence of Object oriented programming, In the example you have taken. Animal is a prototype(Ideally this should be your interface) which defines the characteristics of an animal. Which means anything that you call an animal should have these features. That's how you are binding all animals to be of type Animal. You will get a clear picture when you look at it from a design perspective.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and your help. I'm still learning OOP right now, so I'm slowly starting to understand bits and pieces of OOP and software design. I also have another question: when would it be best to use interface vs inheritance? Based on this example, I see pros and cons for interface, extending concrete class Animal and for making an abstract class called animal.